# using variables in a string, to do Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html, variables

Is there a way to use variables in this situation?  I want this code:

> String str = "test";
>   Html.fromHtml("test <.bold> str <./bold> test");

to make:

> test **test** test

but instead it makes:

> test **str** test

Thanks

Comment: You included "str" inside the quotes. It is a variable and should be added outside quotes as teepee has answered below.

Comment: `<.bold>` is not valid HTML and is not honored by `Html.fromHtml()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

```
String str = "test";
textView.setText( Html.fromHtml("test <bold>" + str + "</bold> test") );
```

or for a more difficult solution, you can use java's [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for replacing strings defined with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version using an extension function with Android SDK deprecation validation

```kotlin
@Suppress("deprecation")
fun String.fromHtml(): Spanned = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(this)
}

val str = "test"
textView.text = "test <bold>$str</bold> test".fromHtml()
```